# How many monotone injective functions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

New to discrete math. By[n] we mean {1,2,...n}. What is the number of monotone injective functions from [3] to [6]? I understand n choose k formula but it doesn't seem to solve the question. How do I change the calculation if the order between two sets are preserved? If anyone could provide some guidance on how to proceed, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Count the number of ways to assign values to $f(1)=x_1$, $f(2)-f(1)=x_2$ and $f(3)-f(2)=x_3$. The conditions are $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq1$ (for the increasing case) and $x_1+x_2+x_3=f(3)\leq 6$. The latter can be solved by the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: It's just $_6P_3$...

Comment: Why do you think that n choose k does not solve the question? What about [2] to [3]? Can you do that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to choose the $3$ different function values.  In order to make the function monotone, we must arrange them in either increasing or decreasing order, so there are $40$ possible functions in all.

That is, either $f(1)<f(2)<f(3)$ or $f(1)>f(2)>f(3)$.